# Align image view with other Linear Layout elements in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am designing a static week calendar as per the snapshot below. As you can see the dot image is not getting aligned with other items in the Linear layout. This is a Static calendar that displays days in the current week. I had to set button width and height to 40dp else instead of circular background I was getting bit of oval shape for button background when selected. Any pointers on the change required to align the dot icon with other items vertically.

The rounded button style is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

My xml UI layout is as below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayLabel1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="M"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dateBtn1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="13" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dotIcon1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dotindicatoricon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayLabel2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="M"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dateBtn2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="13" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dotIcon2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dotindicatoricon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayLabel3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="M"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dateBtn3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"

            android:text="13" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dotIcon3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dotindicatoricon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayLabel4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="M"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dateBtn4"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"

            android:text="13" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dotIcon4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dotindicatoricon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayLabel5"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="M"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dateBtn5"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"

            android:text="13" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dotIcon5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dotindicatoricon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayLabel6"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="M"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dateBtn6"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"

            android:text="13" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dotIcon6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dotindicatoricon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dayLabel7"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="M"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dateBtn7"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="13" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dotIcon7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dotindicatoricon" />    
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: UI Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gravity="center" should be appropriate, there seems to be an issue `withdotindicatoricon` maybe you set some margins in the xml? or is there a padding somewhere?

Comment: I think a table view would be a good choice instead of linear layout.

Comment: After setting layout_gravity ="center" to all the elements, I see it aligned.

Comment: @HiteshGupta I got this working with Linear layout but feel free to share your layout if you think that makes more sense and if you think it is a good choice. I would love to know about it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid
But for best performance, you should avoid nested LinearLayouts (it actually will crash one you if you nest weighted LinearLayouts) and use ConstraintLayout instead, but i think you're Layout is pretty fine as is, ConstraintLayout would really be a pain in this case.